# Mac Apps Store wont download any apps on computer

Tags: applications, data-transfer, mac-appstore

I have successfully downloaded apps on a laptop, but when trying to download on a desktop mac, whenever i click install, it says 'put password for billing info', as it would normally. I do so, click enter, and nothing happens.  No error message, nothing.

Comment: Are you an admin on that computer?

Comment: have you tried signing out then signing back in with your iTunes account?

Comment: thanks, singing out and in worked. It let me confirm my details then. I don't if i'm supposed to do anything to show that your answer is right (i'm new)

Comment: I'll add my response as an answer then you can check the checkmark.  Thanks, glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try signing out of your iTunes account then signing back in.